# Trigger to prevent infinite loop in a sql tree

Tags: sql, tree, loops, triggers

I have node table with (NodeId, NodeName) and structure table (ParentNodeId, ChildNodeId). How can I write a trigger that check if an insert update or delete statement can cause infinite relation?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution, and so far it works as expected.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CheckNodeDependence] ON [dbo].[ObjectTrees]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @CTable TABLE(ChildId INT NOT NULL,
                          ParentId INT NOT NULL,
                          [Level] INT NOT NULL,
                          RowId INT NOT NULL)

    DECLARE @Level INT
    SET @Level = 1

    DECLARE @rows_affected INT
    SET @rows_affected = 1

    INSERT INTO @CTable
    SELECT ObjectId, ParentId, 1, ObjectId FROM INSERTED

    WHILE @rows_affected > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Level = @Level + 1
        INSERT INTO @CTable
        SELECT T.ObjectId, T.ParentId, @Level, C.RowId
            FROM ObjectTrees T
                INNER JOIN @CTable C ON T.ParentId = C.ChildId
                AND C.Level = @Level - 1

            SET @rows_affected = @@rowcount
            IF EXISTS(
                SELECT * FROM @CTable B
                    INNER JOIN @CTable V ON B.level = 1
                    AND V.Level > 1
                    AND V.RowId = B.RowId
                    AND V.ChildId = B.RowId)
            BEGIN
                    DECLARE @error_message VARCHAR(200)
                    SET @error_message = 'Operation would cause illegal circular reference in tree structure, level = ' + CAST(@Level AS VARCHAR(30))
                    RAISERROR(@error_message,16,1)
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                    RETURN
            END
        END
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to recursively check the circular dependency condition in which the parent doesn't become a child of its own child, either directly or indirectly.

In SQL Server 2005, you can write a recursive CTE for the same. An example -

```
WITH [RecursiveCTE]([Id], [ParentAccountId]) AS
(
    SELECT
        [Id],
        [ParentAccountId]
    FROM [Structure]
    WHERE [Id] = @Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        S.[Id],
        S.[ParentAccountId]
    FROM [Structure] S INNER JOIN [RecursiveCTE] RCTE ON S.[ParentAccountId] = RCTE.[Id]
)
SELECT * FROM [RecursiveCTE]
```

Comment: but once found, what is the best way to cause an insert/update to fail using a trigger?

Comment: Depends on the platform.  In Oracle you would throw an exception, hopefully with as much helpful information as possible in the text.  But really, it depends on the application, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. It depends on the application you are using. In SQL Server also you'll throw an exception to stop the insert. Or you can use Instead Of triggers and do nothing.

Comment: I agree with both comments, mine was intended to imply that the questioner wanted to know both "how to find the issue" and then "how to use a trigger to prevent it" :)